# PHPUnit stalling or exhausting memory since upgrading to Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, homestead, laravel-5.6

I had a working test suite however two things have change on my local environment. 1) I've upgrade Homestead to version 7 and 2) I've upgraded my app to Laravel 5.6.

Now I'm having issues with PHPUnit exhausting memory allocation unless I add `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` to the start of my `createApplication` method. My test suite then progresses a bit further but eventually stalls entirely.

The strange thing is if I run the test that the suite stalls on in isolation it passes. In fact if I just test the entire file, which may contain 10 tests, the tests all pass. It only stalls when trying to test the entire suite in one go...

It's as if things aren't getting cleaned up between tests it's just filling up memory and freezing.

But I'm using the default TestCase `tearDown` method:

```
/**
 * Clean up the testing environment before the next test.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function tearDown()
{
    if ($this->app) {
        foreach ($this->beforeApplicationDestroyedCallbacks as $callback) {
            call_user_func($callback);
        }

        $this->app->flush();

        $this->app = null;
    }

    $this->setUpHasRun = false;

    if (property_exists($this, 'serverVariables')) {
        $this->serverVariables = [];
    }

    if (property_exists($this, 'defaultHeaders')) {
        $this->defaultHeaders = [];
    }

    if (class_exists('Mockery')) {
        if ($container = Mockery::getContainer()) {
            $this->addToAssertionCount($container->mockery_getExpectationCount());
        }

        Mockery::close();
    }

    if (class_exists(Carbon::class)) {
        Carbon::setTestNow();
    }

    $this->afterApplicationCreatedCallbacks = [];
    $this->beforeApplicationDestroyedCallbacks = [];

    Artisan::forgetBootstrappers();
}
```

Which from my understand so reset everything between tests.

I'm using sqlite in memory as my database for testing.

Anyone else experience problems since upgrading?

---

#### Update

I eventually got to the bottom of this. It was an issue with PHP 7.2. Downgrading to 7.1 and all tests passed no problem on default memory limit.

Comment: I do know that the `setUp()` method will be run right before every test, so if you're keeping something in memory there that may be part of the issue? Maybe something that isn't getting cleared in `tearDown()`?

Comment: I set the driver on the filesystem and remigrate the database on setUp but apart from that nothing is being stored during setup as far as I can tell beyond the default `parent::setUp` in TestCase...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I only got it running with `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` and with Kris Wallsmith [tearDown cleanup code](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/18029585104/faster-phpunit)

Comment: @RyanTaylor Do you know what the issue with PHP 7.2 is? Your current environment is Laravel 5.6 and Homestead v7.1.2 with PHP 7.1, right?